# How can i get double quoted characters from a string in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have a string in a file:

```
str = hi "Sonal"
```

I am able to fetch this line of file in a string. Now I want to fetch the characters between the double quotes. i.e. `Sonal`. How can I do it in ruby?

Answer (score 4):

try the following

```
'hi "Sonai"'.match(/"(?<inside_quote>.+)"/)[:inside_quote]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression like this,

```
given_string[/\".*\"/]
```

This will match the characters under quotes.

Comment: It gives character with double quotes. I dont want double quote in output. I want only the string?

Comment: use given_string[/\"(.*)\"/,1]

Answer (score 0):

or without regexp try something like this s[s.index('"')..s.rindex('"')]